# Failed to resolve: com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0 - android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to use below link as a library:

https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager

I have added that library in my `gradle`, but I've got this error message:

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0
```

my `gradle` :

```
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar'){
        transitive = true
    }
```

**updated**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    } }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

Comment: Can you show your top level build.gradle. This gradle file doesn't seem to have any issue. Try adding this class path " classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1"

Comment: Here I put my top level build.gradle

Comment: Ah I think you have to add "jcenter()" since it is a jcenter project "allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    } }"

Clean and sync again

Comment: I'd tried jcenter() too, but it didn't work and i'd got same error message

Comment: Try this https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager/issues/113

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar'){
        transitive = true
    }
```

with this

```
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

remove this line in your app/build.gradle

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```